# Unknown equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

While working out a new model for heat transport, I've come up with an equation of the form

$\frac{dF}{dT}\left(\frac{dT}{dx}\right)^2+F\frac{d^2T}{dx^2}=0,$

subject to $T(0)=1$ and $T(1)=0$. In the case where $F$ is independent of the temperature we recover the classical heat equation for steady state heeat conduction and the temperature profile $T(x)=1-x$. However, in general $F$ does not have to be independent of the temperature.

Does anybody have any information about equations of this form? I haven't been able to find anything related to this equation.

Comment: Since $F(T,x)$ is function of two variables, the writing $\frac{dF}{dT}\left(\frac{dT}{dx}\right)^2+F\frac{d^2T}{dx^2}=0$ is ambiguous. Do you mean $\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$ instead of $\frac{dF}{dT}$ ? Or do you mean $\frac{dF}{dT}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dT}$ ? Or, please, express clearly what is $\frac{dF}{dT}$.

Answer (score 1):

In the minimal case, the equation is
$$
F'(T(x))T'(x)^2+F(T(x))T''(x)=0
$$
Divide by $T'$ and $F$ and integrate to get
$$
\ln(F(T(x)))+\ln(T'(x))=c
$$
or
$$
F(T(x))T'(x)=C
$$
which can be integrated again, denoting with $\Phi$ one of the anti-derivatives of $F$,
$$
\Phi(T(x))=Cx+D
$$
With the boundary conditions, $Φ(1)=D$ and $Φ(0)=C+D$, so that you have to solve the implicit equation 
$$
Φ(T(x))=xΦ(0)+(1-x)Φ(1)
$$
for $T(x)$.